# The resolution of some images in my website is too low

Tags: css, image, firefox, rendering, resolution

If you test my app in Firefox, you can see some pines too low resolution.

[You can test my web here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140805012516/http://ecoavantis.com:80/fuertehoteles/)

Change your language to english and press the button "DISCOVER HOW >"

And click on the swimming pool icon:

[image: screenshot]

As you may have noticed, the water-pin shows in lower resolution:

[image: screenshot]

What is the reason for this?

Thank all.

Comment: why haven't you resized the image to the size you need it?  By serving the image so large and making the browser handle the scaling you will be effected in 2 ways - worse performance as it has to download a larger file and bad browser rescaling.  By making the image the size you want it you don't need to worry about how the browser will resize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a quick look at this it doesn't seem that it's showing in lower resolution, but merely Firefox is not doing too well at downscaling the image from 1476px square down to 64px square. I would say try converting the image naturally to 64px using photoshop or something simmilar that will do a good job at downscaling, then Firefox should render it properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pcx2L/1/)

```
img{
    background:url(http://ecoavantis.com/fuertehoteles/images/pin_big_green.png);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;        
}

<img src="transparent.png" />
```